# force reagent component to update on window resize

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to realize a reagent component, which keeps track of the real computed size of it's outer html element. The following works:

```
(defn i-show-my-size []
  (let [size (r/atom nil)]
    (r/create-class {:component-will-mount
                     (fn [this]
                       (set! (.-onresize js/window)
                             (r/force-update this)))
                     :reagent-render
                     (fn []
                       [:div {:ref #(when % (reset! size (let [bb (.getBoundingClientRect %)]
                                                           [(.-width bb) (.-height bb)])))}
                        (prn-str @size)])})))
```

Are there better ways to do so? E.g. Do I need the create-class notation or is it maybe possible without?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can make it work without the form-3 component, using both r/with-let and r/current-component:

```
(defn get-client-rect [node]
  (let [r (.getBoundingClientRect node)]
    {:left (.-left r)
     :top (.-top r)
     :right (.-right r)
     :bottom (.-bottom r)
     :width (.-width r)
     :height (.-height r)}))

(defn size-comp []
  (r/with-let [size (r/atom nil)
               this (r/current-component)
               handler #(reset! size (get-client-rect (rdom/dom-node this)))
               _ (.addEventListener js/window "resize" handler)]
    [:div "new size " @size]
    (finally (.removeEventListener js/window "resize" handler))))
```

Comment: Still, it's somewhat of a special case. If you need to listen to an event that originates from an element, the only way is with a form-3 component (because it's not allowed to use r/dom-node in a render function).

Comment: I like your solution :)

Comment: Now you are just complimenting yourself @TimothyPratley since it's totally built on yours but thanks :P I couldn't add the code in the comments so had to put it up as a new answer.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I have been totally missing `r/with-let`.

Answer (score 1):

0.6.0 introduced `with-let` (http://reagent-project.github.io/news/news060-alpha.html) Their example (below) is very similar to your use case:

```
(defn mouse-pos-comp []
  (r/with-let [pointer (r/atom nil)
               handler #(swap! pointer assoc
                               :x (.-pageX %)
                               :y (.-pageY %))
               _ (.addEventListener js/document "mousemove" handler)]
    [:div
     "Pointer moved to: "
     (str @pointer)]
    (finally
      (.removeEventListener js/document "mousemove" handler))))
```

Comment: But the problem is that without a form-3 component notation, you don't have a reference to the component itself (e.g. "this"), no?

Comment: There are (confusingly) several ways to get a reference to the HTML element, and many different forms which will work.